# Problem with login after update

Tags: updates, login, screen, recovery-mode

I have just re-installed twice Ubuntu because of this problem, I'm only able to see the login screen when I use recovery mode and select File System Check.
In other case I just hear the start sound but I can't see anything on my screen, it still works the terminal because I can press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and reboot the system, but I can't see that on the screen, unless as I said using the recovery mode options.
I'm sure it happened after the update because I had been rebooting after any install or copying a file from a USB flash drive and I wasn't seeing any problem before I updated.

I also remember that there was a package that was just downloaded 70% and it automatically changed to another package and I'm not sure it downloaded and installed correctly the package.

Before re-installing, I was not sure about the problem and I even tried configurating gdm and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is very same to your problem, and I solved it this way:.

1. pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. `sudo rm /home/<username>/.Xauthority`
3. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg && sudo reboot`.

   In this step you may see `the following packages have unmet dependencies`. If you see this issue, do a:  `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get -f install`, then issue `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg` again.
4. `sudo reboot`

Comment: It didn't work. I reinstalled it again and then I did dist-upgrade instead the updater and I got the same problem. I entered the system from recovery mode and I did what you said and  it didn't change anything.

Comment: Do you change permissions  on home directory? sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /home/[username]

Comment: no, do I have to do it before or after removing xauthority?

Comment: I recomend you to check your account's authority in home file, cd /home/[username] && ls -l. If some files are root permissions, you should change them